# Got fancy w/ Selection Sort, now it won't sort

Tags: c++, class, sorting

So I'm looking to do your basic selection sort. I copied verbatim from book (with one exception to be listed later). Here's the code.

```
void SelectionSort::sort(int arr[], int size)
{
    int isEqual;
    int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = arr[startScan];

        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {       
            isEqual = counters(arr[index], arr[index + 1]);

            if (isEqual == 1)
            {
                minValue = arr[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];
        arr[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}
```

You'll notice I have an `int isEqual` that is assigned to a method `counters`. I used this because I want to keep a running tally of the comparisons made.

The code for `counters`

```
int AbstractSort::counters(int a, int b)
{
    counter++;
    if (a < b)
        return -1;
    if (a > b)
        return 1;
    if (a == b)
        return 0;   
}
```

Basically, it acts the same as `if (array[index] < minValue)` only this way I can track my comparisons.

I use this method in my QuickSort class, and it sorts the data and counts the comparisons no problem. My SelectionSort however will not sort the data!

[image: SelectionSort Error!]

It looks like it moves the last number in the array to the front, and then does nothing. It does however appear to make 190 comparisons, although I don't particularly see the fruit of it's labor.

I have discussed this code line by line with my rubber duck, but neither of us can seem to catch the error. 
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a debugger.

Comment: isEqual == 1 means a > b means arr[index] > arr[index + 1], but in the body of the if statement you assign arr[index] to a variable called "minValue". arr[index] can't be a minimum if it is greater than arr[index+1], can it? Do you mean isEqual==-1?

Comment: isEqual == 1 and isEqual == -1 only change the order in which the array is sorted. So one runs high to low, the other runs low to high, but doesn't affect my ability to run through the sort (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something that is just like `if (array[index] < minValue)` then you should probably pass `minValue` to your `counters` function.

Comment: That wouldn't compare neighboring array values though, would it? I keep it the way I have it so that I can work from the right side to the left side, swapping as I go until everything is sorted from the left to the right.

Comment: I guess I'm too new to c++ to understand how that would still work. My counters class takes two int values from two neighbor elements. Does passing minValue to my counter function still do the same thing? Because min value is just the current lowest value it has found. Also, I was not the -1. I can set you back to 0 though.

Comment: Yes, you can pass `minValue` in. And if you do it will then be the current lowest value.

Answer (score 2):

```
isEqual = counters(arr[index], arr[index + 1]);
```

This line of code compares subsequent elements and finds the lesser.  So the inner loop finds the last item that was less than the preceding item, and does not find the minimum in the range.  Instead of comparing against the previous, compare against the minimum:

```
isEqual = counters(arr[index], minValue);
```

(As a note, `arr[index + 1]` also reads past the end of the array, so you got lucky it didn't crash)

Answer (score 1):

Your selection sort is incorrect.

First, "isEqual" is *not* equal.

Second, you should be finding the smallest value in the (unsorted) remainder of the array. Instead, you are comparing every adjacent pair.

```
is_less_if_lt0 = counters(arr[index], minValue);
```

Update `minValue` and `minIndex` as needed.

Hope this helps.